# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__call__'

Tags: python, web, flask, flask-login

I am working on the templates in flask application.
While trying to work on the authentication for when a user is logged in or not,
I keep recieving the error

`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__call__'`

I have this written in my templates/base.html

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
<li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Sign Out</a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Sign In</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

I have no idea while this is happening, I have also written this in the view function for calling the template, if this might be the reason,

`from flask import current_user`

but still it does the same thing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

`is_authenticated` is a referencing a bool value. You can't call a bool value.

remove `()` from `is_authenticated` should solve the error

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
<li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Sign Out</a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Sign In</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `is_authenticated` without `()` because `is_authenticated` is property, not a function

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `current_user.is_authenticated` is a boolean value, but you're trying to `__call__` it as a function by appending the () behind it.

Just call it as `current_user.is_authenticated`

Comment: Thank You, figured that out right now. Did not know the `AttributeError '__call__' `meant it was not callable as a function

Comment: @chidonna you should accept Danielle's answer if it helps you resolve your issue.